# Unable to plot first point using `set log x`, `set log y` under `gnuplot`

Tags: scale, gnuplot, logarithm

I am trying to plot two graphs using different columns from the same data file.  As the range of one graph is far greater than the other, I am setting the y-axis to a logarithmic scale.  As the domain of values are also very small for both graphs, I am also setting the x-axis to a logarithmic scale.

I have no problem plotting the graphs except that `gnuplot` does not plot the first points in the data file (where x = 0).

The code that I am using to plot the graphs is thus:

```
set xrange [1:2500]
set yrange [1:2000]
set log x
set log y
plot "datafile.txt" using 1:2 with lines, "datafile.txt" using 1:3 with lines
```

Note that, because I am using a logarithmic scale for both axes, I cannot include the value of zero in either range.

An excerpt of the data file that I am using is thus:

```
Table of Results: Range: {-50...50}
Dim #AvgP   #AvgNP
0   0   1743
1   0   564
2   0   914
3   0   1040
4   0   1072
5   0   1005
6   0   815
7   1   689
8   3   525
9   4   433
10  3   350
11  0   255
12  1   216
13  2   140
14  2   84
15  1   57
16  0   38
17  0   16
18  0   15
19  1   7
20  0   2
21  0   1
22  0   1
23  0   0
24  0   0
25  0   0
.   .   .
.   .   .
.   .   .
```

The file that is plotted is thus:

[image]

Notice how the first value of the second graph is not plotted.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you note, the *x=0* point isn't defined on a logarithmic axis, so it being omitted is what you should expect to happen. If you want to force that point to be included, shift the *x* values by adding 1 to each value, and give an appropriate axis label to make clear what it being plotted.

```
plot "datafile.txt" using ($1+1):2 with lines, "datafile.txt" using ($1+1):3 with lines
```

With this, you should see the missing point on the green line. The red line will be unchanged, as the value *y=0* can't be plotted either. You could shift the *y* values as well, if desired.

Here's how it looks:
[image: curve shifted to show first point.]

Comment: @MichaelJBarber - Thanks for your help but, when I tried this, it shifted both graphs to the right by 1, and still did not plot the first point.  Any other suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: All I can say is that it works here. I've edited in a description of the expected changes. If that doesn't describe what you're seeing, then I've nothing to suggest other than editing your question to provide details about what version of gnuplot you're using.

Comment: @MichaelJBarber - Thanks for the feedback.  I'll have a little fiddle around with it, and see what I can come up with.  FYI - I have GNUPLOT version 4.4 patchlevel 3, which was last modified in March 2011.  It is a Darwin port (ver. 11.2.0) or MacPort that is running under the latest MacOS X operating system (Lion).  Also, the AquaTerm software which it uses to display the graph is also a MacPort, and currently stands at Version 1.0.1.

Comment: I have the same setup -- most recent OS, most recent MacPorts install.  I've also tried it under cygwin, with success.